# Make 'Q' close out program

Tags: c++

Need program to close if Q or q is entered.

But at the moment it does not it just closes and displays the phone number and closes.

If you can help me please post thank you!

I currently have this code so far and it works but the while loop i doesnt as it doesnt stop if -5 is returned.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int readDial ( char &d1, char &d2, char &d3, char &d4, char &d5, char &d6,  char &d7, char &d8);

char toDigit (char &d);

void acknowledgeCall (char d1, char d2, char d3, char d4, char d5, char d6, char d7, char d8);

int main ()
{
    char d1, d2, d3, d4 , d5, d6, d7, d8;

    int returnV = false;

    while (returnV != -5)
    {
        returnV = readDial (d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8);
        switch (returnV)
        {
        case -1: cout << "Error - An invalid Character was entered.\n";
        case -2: cout << "Error - Phone Number cannot begin with 0.\n";
        case -3: cout << "Error - Phone Number cannot begin with 555.\n";
        case -4: cout << "Error - Hyphen is not in the correct spot.\n";
        default: acknowledgeCall (d1, d2, d3,d4, d5,d6,d7,d8);
        }
    }




    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int readDial ( char &d1, char &d2, char &d3, char &d4, char &d5, char &d6,  char &d7, char &d8)
{
    int returnV;

    cout << " Enter The Phone Number (Q to Quit): ";
    cin >> d1;
    if( d1 == 'Q' || d1 == 'q')
    return -5;
    cin >> d2 >> d3 >> d4 >> d5 >> d6 >> d7 >> d8;
    returnV = toDigit(d1);

    if (returnV == -1)
        return returnV;
    returnV = toDigit(d2);

    if (returnV == -1)
        return returnV;
    returnV = toDigit(d3);

    if(d4 != '-')
        return -4;

    returnV = toDigit(d5);


    if (returnV == -1)
        return returnV;
    returnV = toDigit(d6);

    if (returnV == -1)
        return returnV;
    returnV = toDigit(d7);

    if (returnV == -1)
        return returnV;
    returnV = toDigit(d8);


    if (returnV == -1)
        return returnV;
    if (d1 == '0')
        return -2;
    if (d1 == '5' && d2 == '5' && d3 == '5')
        return -3;
    return 0;
}

char toDigit (char &d)
{
    d = toupper (d);
    switch (d)
    {
    case '0': case '1' : case '2' : case '3': case '4' : case '5' : case '6' : case '7' : case '8' : case '9':
        break ;

    case 'A' : case 'B' : case 'C':
        d = '2';
        break;

    case 'D' : case 'E' : case 'F' :
        d = '3';
        break ;

    case 'G' : case 'H' : case 'I' :
        d = '4';
        break ;

    case 'J' : case 'K' : case 'L' :
        d = '5';
        break ;

    case 'M' : case 'N' : case 'O' :
        d = '6';
        break ;

    case 'P' : case 'Q' : case 'R' : case 'S' :
        d = '7' ;
        break ;

    case 'T' : case 'U' : case 'V' :
        d = '8' ;
        break ;

    case 'W' : case 'X' : case 'Y' : case 'Z' :
        d = '9' ;
        break;

    default: return -1;
    }
}

void acknowledgeCall (char d1, char d2, char d3, char d4, char d5, char d6, char d7, char d8)
{

    cout << " Phone Number Dialed: " << d1 << d2 << d3 << d4 << d5 << d6 << d7 <<d8 << " \n\n ";

}
```

Comment: you might wanna use breaks in that switch statement

Comment: You never handle the newline that `cin` returns when the user presses Enter.

Answer (score 0):

You have a major logic problem in your main().

Check your `switch:case` logic and add necessary handling for the input of Q/q

Answer (score 0):

You have used `default` case in the switch case, which means that that case is worked out for all other values than the ones mentioned above. So if you dont specify for `returnV=5`, the default case is executed. so add this statement before the default case:

```
case -5: exit(1)
```

This will cause the program to exit if returnV is -5. 
And using break statement between cases in switch, causes the control to leave the switch-case after a single case is executed. If you dont use, all the cases after the original case needed are executed. So add `break;` at the end of each case